# Is there any convention for current source symbols like this?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, current-source, symbol

In the [page 26](http://ecee.colorado.edu/%7Eecen5807/course_material/Ch12slides.pdf) of this lecture note, there are two symbols used for the current sources. The first one is circle and the second one is square.
Is there any rule or convention for this?

[image]

Comment: They seem to come in all shapes, circles, double circles. squares, diamonds...

Comment: You work with  SMPS design theory far above the practical electrician level. The lecturer uses as much symbols as he needs to keep the ambiguity out. The drawing is not a circuit, it's an alternative presentation for the math small signal model. I must admit I have no idea how the graphic version is better than the equation, but the lecturer can have a simulator which accepts graphical formula input.

Answer (score 1):

The de facto standard for textbooks in the U.S. is that ideal independent source use a circle, with plus and minus for a voltage source or an arrow for a current source.

Dependent sources use a diamond instead of a circle.

Comment: The current sources here are a different from normally dependent current sources as the controlling variables are not voltages or currents.

Comment: I am not aware of any requirement that the shape of a source must be different if it is dependent on something that is not a voltage or current.